# PHP within an Iframe not working in IE

Tags: php, html, internet-explorer, iframe

I have a program, that searches a database from a PHP file, linking back to the some file with the output.
It works perfectly in all browsers, excluding IE. I have no idea why. 
Here is my code:

```
<?php
if( isset( $_POST['schoolname'] ) && strlen( trim( $_POST['schoolname'] ) ) > 0  )
{
        $school = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'find', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $school = $_POST['schoolname'];
        #connecting to the database
        $conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "root");
        mysql_select_db("finalproject");

        $sql = "select * from presentations where school like '%$school%'";

        $result = mysql_query($sql, $conn) or die(mysql_error());
        #this is the array that stores and displays the results of the search
        if ( mysql_num_rows($result) >0)
        {
            while ($newArray = mysql_fetch_array($result))
            {
                $school  = $newArray['school'];
                $date = $newArray['date'];
                $place  = $newArray['place'];
                $time = $newArray['time'];


                echo $school . ", " . $place . ", " . $date . ", " . $time . "<br />" . "<br />";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Record not found" . "<br />" . "<br />";
        }



        mysql_close($conn);
}

?>
<!-- The form in which the search happens -->
<form action=" " method="post">
School's name: <input type="text" name="schoolname">
<input type="submit" name="button" value="Search">
</form>
```

This is just my code for within the IFrame.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Hi, you're not specifying in what way it doesn't work. You should do that.

Comment: @Pekka웃 Oh sorry, I meant to put that in. Whenever I run the search, it gives me a "The page cannot be displayed
The page you are looking for cannot be displayed because an invalid method (HTTP verb) was used to attempt access"

Comment: ^^^^as true as it is, its getting a little tedious for regular S.O users to see it 10 times a day.

Comment: PHP has nothing to do with browser, you have to be more specific. - what IE version are you using?
- what do you really mean it doesnt work? when you push the submit button it doesnt submit?

Comment: The error might be the `action=" "` try `action=""`

Comment: @JosephSilber After I manage to get this working I will look into those thank you.

Comment: @Pekka웃 Wow. Thank you. Haha. I cant believe it was that simple.